# Agregar datos entre tablas relacionadas en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Quiero saber si existe una manera mas optima de hacer lo que quiero hacer,

Tengo una tabla A que esta conformada de acuerdo al modelo que les voy a mostrar:

```
class M2m extends Model
{
protected $table = 'm2ms';
public $timestamps = true;

protected $casts = [
    'id_customer' => 'int',
    'dias_contrato' => 'int',
    'dias_pendiente_contrato' => 'int',
    'pausar_contrato' => 'int'
];

protected $dates = [
    'fecha_inicio_contrato',
    'fecha_fin_contrato',
    'fecha_pausa_contrato'
];

protected $fillable = [
    'id_customer',
    'nombre_cliente',
    'numero_serie',
    'numero_telefono_sim',
    'fecha_inicio_contrato',
    'fecha_fin_contrato',
    'dias_contrato',
    'dias_pendiente_contrato',
    'pausar_contrato'
];

public function estados()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Estado::class, 'estados_m2ms')
                ->withPivot('id')
                ->withTimestamps();
}
```

}

Perfecto...luego tengo una tabla B que tiene estos estado de acuerdo al modelo:

```
class EstadosM2m extends Model
{
protected $table = 'estados_m2ms';
public $incrementing = false;
public $timestamps = true;

protected $casts = [
    'id' => 'int',
    'm2m_id' => 'int',
    'estado_id' => 'int'
];

protected $fillable = [
    'm2m_id',
    'estado_id'
];

public function estado()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Estado::class);
}

public function m2m()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(M2m::class);
}
```

}

Como ya se imaginaron, la tabla A es un articulo que una vez que se registra, se debe registrar el estado en la tabla B, ese articulo con el paso del tiempo sufrirá transiciones de estados, por ello se registra como lo ven.

Ahora bien mi pregunta:

Se puede hacer en eloquent que al momento de registrar el articulo, en este caso tabla A en el mismo proceso se pueda registrar el m2m_id de la tabla B que es el atributo que se relaciona con el ID de la tabla A?? a ver, yo he hecho esto de manera rudimentario es decir, primero registro los datos en A, después busco el ID y lo guardaría en la tabla B, pero quiero saber si existe un método (que desconozco completamente) para poder hacer ese registro de una manera diferente.

Espero me puedan entender y me puedan dar alguna idea. Gracias.

/*EDITADO*/

Lo que llevo hecho es esto

```
            $tarjetaM2M = new M2m();
            $tarjetaM2M->nombre_cliente = $nombrecliente;
            $tarjetaM2M->id_customer = $id_customer;
            $tarjetaM2M->numero_serie = $numero_serie;
            $tarjetaM2M->numero_telefono_sim = $numero_telefono_sim;   
            $tarjetaM2M>fecha_inicio_contrato=
            M2m::ConvertirFormatoFechaCarbon($fecha_inicio_contrato);
            $tarjetaM2M->fecha_fin_contrato = 
            M2m::ConvertirFormatoFechaCarbon($fecha_fin_contrato);
            $tarjetaM2M->dias_contrato = $diasdecontrato;
            $tarjetaM2M->save();

            $idTarjetaM2M = M2m::select('id')
                ->orderBy('id','desc')
                ->take(1)
                ->get();

                $idTarjeta='';
                foreach ($idTarjetaM2M as $id)
                {
                    $idTarjeta=$id->id;
                }

            if($idTarjetaM2M)
            {
                $estados = new EstadosM2m();
                $estados->m2m_id = $idTarjeta;
                $estados->estado_id = $estado_id;
                $estados->save();

            }

Pero se que esto se puede hacer mejor.
```

Comment: Muéstranos que llevas al momento por favor

Comment: En Laravel esto se resuelve siguiendo esto de [acá](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models). No te doy una respuesta más elaborada porque no entiendo muy bien lo que necesitas.

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta para que puedan ver lo que tengo hecho en el controlador, al momento de guardar me refiro.

Comment: Si la relación entre tus entidades es de muchos a muchos (*como parece ser por la relación definida en el primer modelo*), entonces en la segunda entidad debería existir otro método con la relación `belongsToMany` para completar la relación. En función de que nos aclares eso podemos comenzar a proponer soluciones

Comment: Correcto: public function estados()
 {
  return $this->belongsToMany(Estado::class, 'estados_m2ms')
     ->withPivot('id')
     ->withTimestamps();
 } Esta relacion la tiene la tabla A

Comment: He actualizado el código para que puedan ver como es que yo resuelvo siempre este problema, pero mi intención escribiendo aquí es para poder mejorar este código y hacerlo mas limpio. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

ya lo he resuelto, dejo la solucion si en el futuro alguien tiene un problema similar:

Despues de hacer el save(), en este caso el primer save era muy simple:

```
      /*Asi es como se agregan datos a tablas pivotes*/
            $estado = Estado::find($estado_id);
            $estado->m2m()->attach($tarjetaM2M);
```

Es decir que ya esto que les mostre, aunque funciona igual de bien, ya no seria necesario ademas de que es mas optimo:

```
$idTarjetaM2M = M2m::select('id')
            ->orderBy('id','desc')
            ->take(1)
            ->get();

            $idTarjeta='';
            foreach ($idTarjetaM2M as $id)
            {
                $idTarjeta=$id->id;
            }

        if($idTarjetaM2M)
        {
            $estados = new EstadosM2m();
            $estados->m2m_id = $idTarjeta;
            $estados->estado_id = $estado_id;
            $estados->save();

        }
```

Explicación:

Es importante tener bien definidas las relaciones a la tabla intersección o pivote desde las tablas principales, ya con eso simplemente se aplica la solución.